# how to get the url for a package in npmjs.com instead of installing with npm

Tags: reactjs, npm, normalizr

I am creating a reactjs based html page.

I want to use normalizr for my data.

I can get the reactjs directly in the html by the following:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.4.2/react.js"></script>
```

But how to get normalizr. I didnt find any such link. Because it says to install using npm.

I want to directly use in the html like reactjs as above so is it possible

Comment: What you want is a CDN, basically a URL from which the module is hosted. You can try this one: https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/normalizr@3.3.0/dist/normalizr.min.js

Comment: is this link mentioned somewhere in https://www.npmjs.com/package/normalizr/v/3.3.0

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [unpkg](https://unpkg.com/#/) to any file from any npm library as a link.

For `normalizr`, the URL would be

https://unpkg.com/normalizr@3.3.0/dist/normalizr.min.js

If you need any other file from `normalizer` repo, you can file the link for the file here

https://unpkg.com/normalizr@3.3.0/dist/

**unpkg** is super-fast and better than most cdns out there.

Comment: is this link mentioned somewhere in https://www.npmjs.com/package/normalizr/v/3.3.0

Comment: No, [unpkg](https://unpkg.com/#/) is not part of npm but rather uses npm's registry along with Cloudflare and Heroku to provide a super-fast CDN. The file you get is directly what's found in the npm registry.

Answer (score 0):

Apart from normalizer, you can also use:

```
npm-cdn
```

https://npm-cdn.herokuapp.com/normalizr@3.3.0/dist/normalizr.min.js

Comment: is this link mentioned somewhere in https://www.npmjs.com/package/normalizr/v/3.3.0

Comment: If you check out the npm-cdn package on npmjs.com, you will find the documentation on how to form an url